# Where do I need to add Toast?

Tags: android

I’m setting up a new android app, and want to add toast. Where do I need to set the Toast? Where should I add toast in the following code?

```
public static final String USERID = "userID";


    loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String userName = username_editText.getText().toString();
            String password = password_editText.getText().toString();

           if(userName == null){
               Toast.makeText(Home.this,"Login Unsuccessful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
           else{
               UserProfile.Users users = dbHandler.readAllInfor(userName);

               if(users == null){
                   Toast.makeText(Home.this,"Invalid username or password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }

               else{
                   int userID = users.getId();
                   Intent editProfIntent = new Intent("com.modelpaper.mad.it17121002.EditProfile");
                   editProfIntent.putExtra(USERID,Integer.toString(userID));
                   startActivity(editProfIntent);

               }
           }
        }
    });
}
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

username_editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.home_userName);
password_editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.home_password);
loginbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.home_loginBtn);
registerbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.home_registerBtn);
final DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler(Home.this);

registerbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent("com.modelpaper.mad.it17121002.ProfileManagement");
            startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: You are showing two `Toasts` in that code already.

Answer (score 0):

You can show toast wherever you want with context.
In your code, you are already displaying two toast and it is on right place.

```
Toast.makeText(Home.this,"Login Unsuccessful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and

```
Toast.makeText(Home.this,"Invalid username or password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

One minor correction with first toast message is that you should have to display message like "Please provide username" instead of "Login Unsuccessful".